Camera projection with geo-nodes
I’m trying to create camera projection with geo-nodes to store image color on point cloud color attribute, but I’m not into trigonometry at all.
What I’d like to achieve is this:

But with geo-nodes - not on a shading level.

Is rephrasing your objective as what follows is correct ? (1) You have an image, imported as an object (a plane ?). (2) You have a point cloud. (3) You have a camera set to look at the image (1) through the point cloud (2). (4) You would like to colour a point according the background pixel seen in line "behind" it.

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ with image and point cloud ?

@StefLAncien, seems I made it work. I shared file in answer. Thanks!

Seems I did it with new 4.2 matricies nodes combining setup I had in shading.

Inside geo-nodes there are 3 drivers - to get camera angle and shift x/y for proper mapping. So to use in defferent scene - be sure to remap those drivers to scene camera.

